# Autoload php files in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, xampp

I have a library called `macro` that I want to include in my project. I want to autoload all the files in the folder `lib`:

```
app
| ...
| lib
| | macro
| | | Search.php
| | | SearchFacade.php
| | | SearchServiceProvider.php
| | otherlib
| | | ...
| | lib4
| ...
| filters.php
| routes.php
```

What do I need to do to **autoload all the files in the folder lib**, I am using `Xampp`, and I am running `Windows 8`.

Is it also possible to include in that folder a few standard `stylesheets` and `javascript scripts`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the autoload section in your `composer.json` and add `app/lib` to it

```
autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/lib",
        ],
```

Then just run `composer dump-autoload` in the command line to update the autoloader.